# OSGi httpService.registerResources() of a local path

Tags: java, http, server, osgi, httpservice

I am trying to register a local path resource(outside OSGi bundle) and it just doesn't work.
It's strange because how else can you use resources that are not already existing in the jar?

Here's my code:

```
protected void bindHttpService(HttpService httpService) 
{
        httpService.registerResources("/testServer/resources", "/resources", null);
        httpService.registerResources("/testServer/pictures", "C:\\mypath\\config\\", null);
```

First one works perfectly (but the resources can't be changed since they're in the jar), but if I put a local path it just ignores it and it returns 'not found'.

Comment: According to the javadoc of registerResources an absolutel path in unix syntax should be accepted.

Comment: httpService.registerResources("/testServer/pictures", "C:/mypath/config", null);
http://127.0.0.1:7090/testServer/pictures/    THIS returns 404, in the case of the other resource it returns UNAUTHORIZED, which means that the picture resource was not created - I think.


Edit: The only thing that could be wrong is the folder path, but I am already using it to read/write files in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

I used a Separate servlet which I registered in the httpService:

```
 httpService.registerServlet("/testServer/pictures", new ImageServlet("C:\myPics\pics"), null, null);
```

The servlet is some code I found quite quickly, so it might not be the best implementation:

```
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String imgPath;    

public ImageServlet(String picPath){
    super();
    imgPath = picPath;
}


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

    ServletContext cntx= req.getServletContext();
    // Get the absolute path of the image
    // retrieve mimeType dynamically

    String filename = imgPath+ "/testpicture2.jpg";
    String mime = cntx.getMimeType(imgPath+ "/testpicture2.jpg");
    if (mime == null) {
      resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
      return;
    }

    resp.setContentType(mime);
    File file = new File(filename);
    resp.setContentLength((int)file.length());

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

    // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     int count = 0;
     while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
       out.write(buf, 0, count);
    }
  out.close();
  in.close();
  }
```

I am still wondering how I can take the local resource using an absolute path without the use of this workaround (which was suggested in another answer) so it would be great if you could still help me!

Answer (score 0):

According to javadoc:

> "If the HttpContext argument is null, a default HttpContext is used (see createDefaultHttpContext())".

The behaviour of the getResource method of the DefaultHttpContext is the following:

> this method calls the context bundle's Bundle.getResource method, and returns the >appropriate URL to access the resource.

If you want to use a filesystem resource, you have to implement your own HttpContext and implement the method getResource

Comment: I already did that, in the end it behaved like the DefaultHttpContext, which in my case did not work.

Comment: can you post your implementation ?